# How to prove using proximity axioms that $E=\bar{E}$, for a closed set $E$?

Tags: general-topology

For the first part

$$x\in E\longrightarrow \{x\}\delta\{x\}\longrightarrow \{x\}\delta((E-\{x\})\cup\{x\})\longrightarrow \{x\}\delta E\longrightarrow x\in\bar{E}\longrightarrow E\subseteq \bar{E}$$

How to prove that $\bar{E}\subseteq E$?

Comment: What are proximity axioms?

Comment: @copper.hat, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space#Definition

Comment: How do you define a closed set then?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, $\bar{E}=\{x:E\delta \{x\}\}$.

Comment: So you have a proof that that definition is a valid Kuratowski closure operator? I do hope you're not just learning this from Wikipedia alone.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, this definition of closed set is given in our lecture notes.

Comment: Link to a copy or add the definition to the question!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, our lecture notes are based on https://i.imgur.com/9mC43oU.png

Comment: So your notes say that the topology is **based** on the closure operation from the proximity. This means that $E$ is closed iff $\overline{E} =E$ **by definition**.  The notes refer to some exercise that I think shows that the given definition is a valid closure operator. But your question itself is true by definition and there is nothing to prove (except the exercise).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is simpler for $E \subseteq \overline{E}$.

Let $x \in E$, so (trivially) $\{x\} \cap E \neq \emptyset$ so axiom 3 (as numbered a la Wikipedia) implies $\{x\}\delta E$ so by definition of the closure (mentioned on the same page), $x \in \overline{E}$.

This holds for any $E$ of course and is the proof of the axiom [K2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms#Kuratowski_closure_operators_and_weakenings) of a Kuratowski closure operator (where said operator is defined as $\overline{E}:= \{x \in X\mid \{x\} \delta E\}$).

If this operator is the way you define closed sets for the proximity space $(X,\delta)$ (as Wikipedia suggests), then "$E$ is closed iff $E=\overline{E}$" is a **definition** so there is nothing to prove. Please elucidate if you define closed sets by some other method.

Are you trying to prove the K-axioms perhaps? It seems so.

Comment: I think the second part could go like this $x\in \bar{E}\longrightarrow E\delta\{x\}\longrightarrow E\cap \{x\}\neq \phi \longrightarrow x\in E$

Comment: @user3741635 that's nonsense because you reverse the implication in axiom 3! Forget it immediately. E.g. in the reals in the standard proximity $\{0\}\delta (0,1)$ but $0 \notin (0,1)$.

Comment: you are right. I think this proof only works for compact proximity space.

Comment: @user3741635 also not for compact ones. The same example works in $[0,2]$ as well. …

Comment: I have found a proof in https://esirc.emporia.edu/bitstream/handle/123456789/2575/Chu%201973.pdf?sequence=1 Page 12.

Comment: @user3741635 Theorem 2.5 on page 6 has the proof based on that author's definition of closed ($E$ closed iff $\forall x: \{x\}\delta E \to x \in E$) and 2.9 on page 8 has the complete proof that $c(A)=\{x\mid \{x\} \delta A\}$ is a Kuratowski closure operator. Page 12 has nothing relevant for this question...

Comment: Yes I meant page 8 2.9 (iv).

Comment: @user3741635 yes, that's a valid proof for the axiom $c(A)=c(c(A))$. So you're done then?